# Apply similar options in SQL alchemy as contains_eager by default to query without specifying relationship path

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, python-3.8

The following pytest passes, as expected:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import contains_eager

@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def populate_db(test_db: Session):
    """Populate db with a single parent with two children that go to different schools."""
    parent_1 = Parent(uuid="1")
    child_1 = Child(uuid="2", parent_uuid="1", school="north")
    child_2 = Child(uuid="3", parent_uuid="1", school="south")
    test_db.add(parent_1)
    test_db.commit()
    test_db.add(child_1)
    test_db.add(child_2)
    test_db.commit()

def test_eager(db: Session):
    """Query for parents based off of weather or their child goes to school 'north'."""
    parent = db.query(Parent).join(Child).filter(Child.school == "north").first()
    # both of the parent children relationships are returned
    assert len(parent.children) == 2

    parent = db.query(Parent).join(Child).options(contains_eager(Parent.children)).filter(Child.school == "north").first()
    # Only one of the parent child relationship returned
    assert len(parent.children) == 1
```

What I would like, is for the behaviour of `contains_eager` to be applied by default (so in this case the first assertion would be false, since only the 1 parent.children relationship would be returned)

Also, I have many instances where I would want this to be applied, so would prefer not to have to define the relationship path each time `.options(contains_eager(Parent.children))`

For example if I added a School model, I wouldn't want to be required to update the options with `School.children`.